# Calculate series: x = (x*7 + y) >> 3

Tags: c++

I'm reading the [UDT](http://udt.sourceforge.net/) source. That is a excellent project, but it is so hard to understand some expressions:

```
m_iRTT = (m_iRTT * 7 + rtt) >> 3;
m_iBandwidth = (m_iBandwidth * 7 + *((int32_t *)ctrlpkt.m_pcData + 5)) >> 3;
```

In short expression form:
**x = (x*7 + y) >> 3**

Can someone explain what this expression does ?

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Excuse me, help me to understand what it doing

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

To spell out `x = (x*7 + y) >> 3`:

`x` is multiplied by 7, then the result added to y, then that result shiftted 3 bits to the right and assigned to `x`.